# Does this have a name? $\vDash(a_1\to(a_2\to(\cdots(a_{n-1}\to a_{n})\cdots)))\leftrightarrow((a_1\wedge a_2\wedge\cdots\wedge a_{n-1})\to a_n)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> For all formula $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_n$,
>
> $$\vDash (\alpha_1\to(\alpha_2\to(\cdots(\alpha_{n-1}\to\alpha_{n})\cdots))) \leftrightarrow ((\alpha_1\wedge \alpha_2\wedge\cdots\wedge\alpha_{n-1})\to \alpha_n) $$

In fact, I proved this theorem when $n = 3$, But I think this is generally true. Does this theorem have a name? And I would be grateful if you give me a hint of a general case proof.

Comment: [Exportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic)) is tha "base" case. Do we need a name for the "general" case ? Maybe *Iterated Exportation* ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much!

Comment: This also corresponds to [uncurrying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Logic) from a propositions-as-types perspective.